# Circle Goes Outside Of Parent Div

Tags: html, css

I have a circle and the right and bottom part of the circle extend slightly outside the parent div.Why is this? How can I fix this?
[image]

```css
.player-holder {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.player-thumb {
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  background-image: url("chat-icon.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player-holder">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="player-thumb"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can fix everything with just one line:

add `box-sizing: border-box` to `.player-thumb`:

```css
.player-holder {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 50px;
}

.player-thumb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  background-image: url("chat-icon.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player-holder">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="player-thumb"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Since no-one explained why it is happening, here is the explanation on what is going on:

In CSS there is a property called `box-sizing` ([Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)), which defines how the dimensions of an element are calculated. There are three options;

- content-box
- padding-box
- border-box

*Note: I'm omitting `initial`, `inherit` and `unset`, because they depend on default values or parent values.*

The image below shows you what the options capture:

[image: box-sizing image]
[Source](https://zellwk.com/blog/understanding-css-box-sizing/)
(*Image re-uploaded at Stack Overflow, because direct link didn't work*)

Content-box is the default, which means whenever you define a width and height, the padding and border sizes are not included in those sizes.

Lets say you define a div which has a height of 100 pixels, the padding-top is 30 pixels and there is a border at the bottom that's 10 pixels:

```
.random_div {
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

Now we'll have to choose a setting for box-sizing:

**Content-box:**

When you wouldn't change the box-sizing, the div would get a total height of 140 pixels (100 + 30 + 10).

**Padding-box:**

When you set box-sizing to padding-box, the div would get a total height of 110 pixels (100 + 10). This is because padding is now included in the 100 pixels of height. This leaves you with 70 pixels of space for content.

**Border-box:**

When you set box-sizing to border-box, the div would get a total height of 100 pixels. All the sizes are included into the height of the div.

Which one you use is up to you. I usually set most of my elements to border-box, because that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have the circle border and so the actual circle width will be of 102px;

See this pen to see how it behaves:

If you need the circle border, then add 2px to the parent div. Also check the circle height;

```
.player-holder {
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 102px;
    min-width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.player-thumb {
    margin: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    min-width: 50px;
    width:100px;

    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    background-image: url("chat-icon.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;

    background-size: 50px;
}
```

Comment: What about the bottom part? I switched the height to 102px but the circle is still outside the parent div

Comment: I edited my comment above.  Check the .player-thumb height

Comment: To be honest, I think [Douwe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563551/3316645) has not only the better solution but also a way better explanation of what is going on. You might want to check that.