# My Left Column in CSS doesn't fit in the div I created

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with positioning my Left Column properly inside the white box I created with the clas "leftcol".

I've done a lot of research but the list always fall out of the white box.

I know this is a very basic problem with CSS but I'm a newbie in the game, so if someone can explain me the theory behind the practice with displaying these kind of information in the page, I'd be very thankful.

```css
/*Global Attributes*/
    
    
    body {  
       font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
       color: purple;
       background-color: grey;  }
    
    h1 {
       font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, Arial, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif   }
    
    address {
       margin-top: 1em;
       padding-top: 1em;
       border-top: thin dotted }
    
    
    
    /*HEADER *****************/
    
    header {
     background-color: white;
     height: 145px;
     border-radius: 1em;
    }
    
    .logotop {
     margin-left: 0.8em;
    }
    
    
    
    #navbar li {
     display: inline;
     background-color: green;
     border: 5px solid #a2ff4a;
     margin: 0.3em 0.5em;
     padding: 0.5em 5em;
     border-radius: 1em;
    }
    
    #navbar li a {
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #navbar li:hover {
     background-color: #a2ff4a;
    }
    
    /* LEFT COLUMN */
    
    .leftcol {
     background-color: white;
     float: left;
     width: 139px;
     height: auto;
     border-radius: 0.5em;
     margin: 2em 0;
    
    }
    
    .leftcol ul {
     width: 129px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    }
    
    .leftcol li {
     list-style: none;
    }
    
    .leftcol li a {
     display: block;
     margin: 2px ;
     padding: 1em;
     color: white;
     background-color: green;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-radius: 0.5em;
    }
    
    .leftcol li a:hover {
     background-color: #a2ff4a;
    }
    
    /* MAIN !!!!!!!!!!! */
    
    main {
     background-color: white;
     margin: 2em 1em;  
     display: inline-block;
     border-radius: 0.5em;
    }
```

```html
   
    <!--Header-->
    
    <header>
     <a href=""><img class="logotop" src="img/logo1.jpg" width="10%"></a>
    
    
     <ul id="navbar">
      <li><a href="">Quem Somos</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Loja Virtual</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Ajude o Aprenda Agora</a></li>
     </ul>
    </header>
    
    
    <!--Left Column-->
    
    <div class="leftcol">
     <div class="courses">
      <ul class="cursos">
       <li><a href="ingles.html">Inglês</a></li>
       <li><a href="frances.html">Francês</a></li>
       <li><a href="espanhol.html">Espanhol</a></li>
       <li><a href="italiano.html">Italiano</a></li>
       <li><a href="alemao.html">Alemão</a></li>
       <li><a href="chines.html">Chinês</a></li>
       <li><a href="japones.html">Japonês</a></li>
       <li><a href="libras.html">Libras</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    <!-- Main content-->
    
    <main>
    
    <h1>My first styled page!</h1>
    
    <p>Welcome to my first webpage, it's the prototype of Aprenda Agora's website.</p>
    
    <p>It doesn't have many things yet, but soon there will be many articles and vids here!!!11!!1!</p>
    
    
    
    <address>Made 18 July 2017<br>
    by myself.</address>
    
    </main>
```

Comment: You should read [this post of me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44557196/circle-goes-outside-of-parent-div/44563551#44563551) I made a while ago to learn more about box-sizing and how dimensions are calculated in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Remove default left padding from `ul` with `.cursos{ padding-left:0 }`:

```css
/*Global Attributes*/

body {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: purple;
  background-color: grey;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, Arial, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif
}

/* LEFT COLUMN */

.leftcol {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 139px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.leftcol ul {
  width: 129px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.leftcol li {
  list-style: none;
}

.leftcol li a {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.leftcol li a:hover {
  background-color: #a2ff4a;
}

.cursos {
  padding-left:0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>First Prototype</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="first.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!--Left Column-->

  <div class="leftcol">
    <div class="courses">
      <ul class="cursos">
        <li><a href="ingles.html">Inglês</a></li>
        <li><a href="frances.html">Francês</a></li>
        <li><a href="espanhol.html">Espanhol</a></li>
        <li><a href="italiano.html">Italiano</a></li>
        <li><a href="alemao.html">Alemão</a></li>
        <li><a href="chines.html">Chinês</a></li>
        <li><a href="japones.html">Japonês</a></li>
        <li><a href="libras.html">Libras</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple change :

```
.leftcol ul {
    width: 129px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
```

To :

```
.leftcol ul {
    width: 129px;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The ul had a "default" padding which comes from your browser.
You should use a reset CSS file like this : [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css)

Answer (score 0):

Please add this class. It's default browser style you need to override this thing. So due to this `webkit-padding-start: 40px` it's displaying the whole ul outside the white box.

```
ul.cursos {
    -webkit-padding-start: 5px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The width you are applying to the `ul`, will be applied to the content-box. The padding and margin are added to that width, which makes everything wider than you would think.

In this case, the standard padding (left) for the `ul` is added to the width and you should remove that:

```
ul.cursos {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

If you want to know more about the content-box or about box-sizing, [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44557196/circle-goes-outside-of-parent-div/44563551#44563551).

Answer (score 0):

The `ul.cursos` tag is having default padding set to 40px; This is causing the list to move to right and not fit the div. Check out the fiddle :-
https://jsfiddle.net/mwfxyggm/2/

Answer (score -1):

Set Width auto in the leftcol class:

```
.leftcol {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    margin: 2em 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`ul` has default `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;`
override it with

```
ul{ -webkit-padding-start: 5px;}
```

Comment: @downvoter, could you give the reason for down voting