# Why is it adding a horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, devexpress-blazor

I am getting a horizontal scroll bar and I can't figure out why. I have reduced it down to as simple as I can. But there's a fair amount here. But this way I am providing what I think is everything relevant.

If there's anything more I should add, please let me know. And is there a way to have the browser provide a single css file of everything relevant to the page? It would be nice if along with the rendered html, there was a way to provide a single css.

The web page is basically a `<h3>` and a form with just one control. I gave the form a blue border to show the form is not the problem. Here's the web page with the scroll to the left.

[image]

And here it is fully scrolled right

[image]

As you can see, the form is the width of the browser so it's not causing the scroll bar - unless there's something that adds margin to the form's right, which I could not find. There's definitely no margin to the form's left.

Here's the raw html (browser view page source):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="_content/DevExpress.Blazor.Themes/blazing-berry.bs5.min.css?v=coGWgpNGDM1Wzc18lTxde46RTppTfW9Oz4m8mCTmpf0" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="LouisHowe.web.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <script src="/js/Interop.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main b-jv8gxb7csr>
        <div class="my-main-scrollbar" b-jv8gxb7csr>
            <h3>Dashboard</h3>
            <form style="border: 5px solid blue;">
                <div id="idfdca2d08-f895-43e0-922c-d655c9bb9588" class="dxbl-fl dxbl-fl-loading">
                    <div class="dxbl-row">
                        <dxbl-form-layout-item class="dxbl-col-md-12 dxbl-col dxbl-fl-item dxbl-fl-item-horizontal" id="id31058717-b0c5-4528-9b0f-2142faf1d24d">
                            <label class="dxbl-fl-cpt dxbl-text">
                                Full name:
                            </label>
                            <div class="dxbl-fl-ctrl">
                                <dxbl-input-editor id="id955558a4-4ae4-44e2-bd8a-ee978babe2f6" class="valid dxbl-text-edit" bind-value-mode="OnLostFocus">
                                    <input name="id955558a4-4ae4-44e2-bd8a-ee978babe2f6" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="idaab9cdbd-47f2-4b14-a075-5c553a2c28f5"></input>
                                </dxbl-input-editor>
                            </div>
                        </dxbl-form-layout-item>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_vs/browserLink" async="async" id="__browserLink_initializationData" data-requestId="2611f4ebf7d54be7a31d7c9120f10b14" data-requestMappingFromServer="false" data-connectUrl="http://localhost:65118/e19ec81e873b426a9ed54d25b9b587bc/browserLink"></script>
    <script src="/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the computed css for `<body>`

[image]

And for `<main>`

[image]

And for `<div class="my-main-scrollbar">`

[image]

And for the form

[image]

I can't find anything that is adding that little bit of width. But here's a bit of weirdness. If the EditForm is set to `width:99%`, then no scroll bar. So it's adding something to the right of the form. But what/how?

[image]

Comment: To view the css sources in chrome you open dev tools (I use `f12` to open), navigate to sources, then on the left there's a list of all the used files served to the browser rendering the page.

Comment: I would like to help but the only way I can do that efficiently is if you provide a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/2518285) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It is likely that the border is making the width more than 100%, however that shouldn't happen since there is `box-sizing: border-box`. Check if that is applied properly, and try adding the box-sizing property to the form as an inline style and see if anything changes.

Comment: If you could provide code sandbox link of above code then it will easy to debug.

Comment: That's a lot better.  If you look in dev mode, at the bottom of the right side when inspecting, you'll see a collection of boxes-- the main element, the padding, the margin, etc.  What does that look like?

Comment: probably some style/conflict from _other 4_ stylesheets you're including.. (and that JS in the bottom is also suspicious..).. impossible to say

Comment: @DavidThielen The snippet doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think the question was answered here: [Circle Goes Outside Of Parent Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44557196/circle-goes-outside-of-parent-div).

Comment: Okay, I'm on the same page as you now.  The entire box and border display onscreen without needing to scroll, indicating that the `border-box` setting isn't the problem.  So it must be that one of the `dxbl` elements isn't meant to be used at 100% width-- probably some kind of column with padding.

Comment: @asyncawait Yes it lists all the files under sources, but there are 31 .js files, 7 .css files, and  70 .scss files. I'm using DevExpress, the issue only occurs using their components, and that brings in all these external files.

Comment: _What should I have done different in this question?_ - mention frameworks other than bootstrap that you're using and add as much as information possible relevant to each framework, if it's not possible to create a snipppet to reproduce it, at minimum add [devexpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devexpress) tag

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. If you want to ask/discuss how to phrase or ask your question, please ask that on [meta].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've been able to create a possible minimal reproducible example:

```
<div style="height:500px;width:100%;background-color:blue">
    <EditForm Model=Main>
        <div style="width:100%; border: 1px solid black; background-color:pink; margin:2px;">Some stuff</div>
    </EditForm>
</div>
```

I think you'll find that one or more of the `dxbl` classes have non-0 margins, which would make a lot of sense since they are clearly column formatters.

Comment: First off, thanks for continuing to give me feedback. Second, that was it. <dxbl-form-layout-item> had a left & right margin of -12. Set that to 0 and problem solved.

Comment: Nice.  Most of us who have done fullstack web dev have been put into a homicidal rage by CSS at some point.  For me, it's always been: "Will my site display properly on Apple products?" (which until just the last few years, it almost never would).  Last comment-- inline `style` overrides class definitions, so that's where you want to set your margins to 0, rather than changing the actual `dxbl` class.

Comment: Yeah - CSS can bring the worst out in all of us. I really appreciate you sticking with this in spite of that. I've presently got a question in to DevExpress because I want to understand why it's doing this. I always try to fix these things the "right" way as that leads to fewer problems long term. Again, thanks.